# What is the order of asynchronous replication in Active Geo-Replication feature of Azure SQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database

In SQL Azure, Active Geo-Replication asynchronously replicates committed transactions from the primary database to up to four secondary databases on different servers. Does the asynchronous action happen independently on all the four secondaries? Or is this action chained where-in asynchronous action first happens from primary to secondary and then from the first secondary to the second secondary and then second secondary to third secondary and finally from the third secondary to the fourth secondary? If this process is chained does Azure SQL allow the user to identify the chained root secondary till the leaf most secondary to mitigate the replication lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replication is asynchronous to up to four secondaries. It is not chained.

That being said, you *can* create secondaries of a secondary. In that scenario, replication is chained to the secondaries of the secondary.